# Laravel Redis Queue

Tags: redis, laravel-5.3

OK, so I'm new to Redis. However, I'm trying to implement the laravel queue using redis. I know there are better tools I could use, but want to use this as my first step to learning redis.
So here is the issue, I have setup my driver to use redis for queue. However, each time I run `php artisan queue:work --daemon` or `php artisan queue:work` only I'm always greeted by this response which only comes up in log file: `ErrorException: Redis::eval() expects at most 3 parameters, 5 given in...`.
When I used database as my driver, it worked without fuss.

Please help!!!

Comment: Please provide more information. Where do you use Redis::eval? Where does the error appear?

Comment: Oh.. Well. Have you checked your config? Please show it to us (without any sensitive data)

Comment: I didn't use in my code directly, I'm applying redis as my queue driver. I went through the laravel source code to find where it was used.
`
$this->getConnection()->eval(LuaScripts::migrateExpiredJobs(), 2, $from, $to, $this->getTime())
`
Found at [Illuminate\Queue\RedisQueue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/RedisQueue.php)

Comment: I used the default config provided by laravel 5.3. Didn't change it because it works with my redis config.